# PL/SQL Fetches more than requested number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I get this error and I don't know how to fix it..

> DECLARE
> *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
> ORA-06512: at line 7

This is my code which has to count the output from the SQL statement and just print the number but it won't work

```
sqlplus -S "/ as sysdba " <<EOF > /home/oracle/testDaten/Ausgabe.log
set verify off;
set serveroutput on;
set lines 12345 pages 12345;

DECLARE

cnt NUMBER(10);

BEGIN

select count(v.name) into cnt
  from cdb_objects c, v\$containers v
 where object_type like '%JAVA%'
   and c.con_id = v.con_id
   and owner not in ('MDSYS', 'OJVMSYS')
   and c.con_id != 1
   group by v.name
    having count(*) > (select count(*) from cdb_objects c2 
                where object_type like '%JAVA%' 
                and c2.con_id = 1 
                and owner not in ('MDSYS', 'OJVMSYS'));
    

    DBMS_Output.put_line(cnt);
 
end;
/
EXIT
EOF
```

Comment: Why you have use group by clause here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PL/SQL, a bare SELECT into a variable must return exactly one row. If it returns zero rows, you will get a `ORA-01403` (no data found) exception, and if it returns more than one row, you get the `ORA-01422` (exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows) error that you have.

The problem is that your query will return multiple rows, because of the join with `v$containers`.

The solution is easy: Use a cursor loop to loop through the individual records and print them one by one.

```
BEGIN
  for rec in (
    select v.name, count(v.name) cnt
      from cdb_objects c, v$containers v
     where object_type like '%JAVA%'
       and c.con_id = v.con_id
       and owner not in ('MDSYS', 'OJVMSYS')
       and c.con_id != 1
       group by v.name
        having count(*) > (select count(*) from cdb_objects c2 
                    where object_type like '%JAVA%' 
                    and c2.con_id = 1 
                    and owner not in ('MDSYS', 'OJVMSYS'))
  )loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.name || ': ' || rec.cnt);
  end loop; 
end;
/
```

Here surround the query with `for rec in ( ... ) loop ... end loop;`
The record is implicitly defined and you can call it anything (I used `rec`).

Reference the returned columns within the loop just as you would table columns, using the record variable.

A few nice side effects:

- You don't need to declare the count variable now, since it's part of the implicit record.
- There is no need to open, fetch, and close the cursor, this is all done for you.
- A "no data found" condition will never happen; the loop will simply not loop if there are no matching records.

Answer (score 1):

Your GROUP BY clause is the culprit here. Just get rid of and you are good to go -

```
DECLARE
cnt NUMBER(10);

BEGIN

     SELECT count(v.name)
       INTO cnt
       FROM cdb_objects c, v\$containers v
      WHERE object_type like '%JAVA%'
        AND c.con_id = v.con_id
        AND owner NOT IN ('MDSYS', 'OJVMSYS')
        AND c.con_id != 1
      -- group by v.name
      -- HAVING count(*) > (SELECT count(*)
      --                    FROM cdb_objects c2 
      --                   WHERE object_type LIKE '%JAVA%'
      --                     AND c2.con_id = 1
      --                     AND owner NOT IN ('MDSYS', 'OJVMSYS'));

    DBMS_Output.put_line(cnt);

end;
/
```

If you really want to use that, Please share your expected result.

Comment: i want to select all databases which has more objects than other databases..
like this: 
database 1 has 10 java objects and database 2 and 3 have 13 java objects 

so he has to show me database 2 and 3 so (count = 2) thats why i group them with having

Comment: Do you want the owner (Database) which has the maximum no of objects?

Comment: no im working on a multitenant Database which has more than one database thats why im joining the v$containers which gives me the name of the databases

So for example there  is a Container Database


CDB$ROOT <- u cant save any user objects in there
PDB1 which can have user objects so if pdb1 has more java objects than cdb$root java is used and when not its not used thats why i try to count and then i want to create a if and else case